# How to Filter Values from a Nilable Array Using Query Expressions

Tags: arrays, filter, ballerina

I want to select specific fields from a record with the record type `Student[]?` in Ballerina.

In the code below, `classes[className]` has the type `Student[]?`.

`Student[]` is iterable but `Student[]?` is not.

Why is that and how does it figure that out?

```
import ballerina/io;

type Student record {|
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    string address;
    string className;
|};

function getStudentNames(map<Student[]> classes) returns map<string[]> {
    map<string[]> studentNames = {};

    foreach string className in classes.keys() {
        string[] names = [];
        foreach Student student in classes[className] {
            names.push(student.firstName + " " + student.lastName);
        }
        studentNames[className] = names;
    }

    return studentNames;
}
```

Comment: Please come up with a better title. This title is very ambiguous and doesn't describe what the topic of the question is.

Comment: This question is not about Ballerina [query action](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/query-actions/) but about [nillable type](https://ballerina.io/learn/language-basics/#nil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Student[]?` is a union type which means the value can be either an array of Student or nil. You can iterate classes[className] in the foreach (and similarly query expression) only if it is a Student[] and is not nil. So you need to narrow the type down/handle the nil scenario.

For example,

```
function getStudentNames(map<Student[]> classes) returns map<string[]> {
    map<string[]> studentNames = {};

    foreach string className in classes.keys() {
        string[] names = [];
        if classes[className] is Student[] {
            Student[] students = <Student[]> classes[className];
            foreach Student student in students {
                names.push(student.firstName + " " + student.lastName);
            }
        }
        
        studentNames[className] = names;
    }

    return studentNames;
}
```

Simply you can do as follows by using the `map` function in an array.

```php
function getStudentNames(map<Student[]> classes) returns map<string[]> {
    map<string[]> studentNames = {};

    foreach string className in classes.keys() {
        string[] names = classes[className] is Student[] ? (<Student[]> classes[className]).map(student => student.firstName + " " + student.lastName) : [];
        
        studentNames[className] = names;
    }

    return studentNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `Student[]?` in Ballerina denotes an array with either null or students. The`?` denotes the possibility of the array being nullable. Before iterating over the elements of a nullable array, a null check must be done.

```
import ballerina/io;

type Student record {|
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    string address;
    string className;
|};

function getStudentNames(map<Student[]> classes) returns map<string[]> {
    map<string[]> studentNames = {};

    foreach string className in classes.keys() {
        string[] names = [];
        // check if array is not null
        if classes[className] != null {
            foreach Student student in classes[className] {
                names.push(student.firstName + " " + student.lastName);
            }
        }
        studentNames[className] = names;
    }

    return studentNames;
}
```

Comment: Ballerina doesn't have null. Instead Ballerina has [nil](https://ballerina.io/learn/language-basics/#nil) data type that denotes the absence of any other value. The nil value can also be written as `null` but that is only for compatibility with JSON. The use of null should be restricted to JSON-related contexts.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I'm using Ballerina's powerful *query expression*. Note how easily you can create named and reusable query expressions by wrapping them in functions.

The trick I use here to handle nillable array type `Student[]?` is *elvis operator* `x ?: y` that returns `x` if it is not nil or `y` otherwise. I.e:

```
students ?: []
```

returns and empty array if `students` is nil.

Relevant sections from the fine documentation:

- [By Example: Nil](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/nil/)
- [Language Basics: Nil](https://ballerina.io/learn/language-basics/#nil)
- [By Example: Query Expressions](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/query-expressions/)
- [Data: Query Expressions](https://ballerina.io/learn/data/#query-expressions)

```
import ballerina/io;

type Student record {|
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string className;
|};

public function main() {
    Student[]? students = [
        {firstName: "Curt",    lastName: "Christison", className: "Biology"},
        {firstName: "Lynton",  lastName: "Dobson",     className: "Physics"},
        {firstName: "Garnett", lastName: "Attwood",    className: "Economics"},
        {firstName: "King",    lastName: "Tirrell",    className: ""},
        {firstName: "Kerrie",  lastName: "Adkins",     className: "Physics"}
    ];

    // 1/3 unique class names
    string[] classNames = 
        from var {className} // record destructuring
        in students ?: [] // elvis operator
        where className.length() > 0 // filter
        group by className // unique
        order by className // order
        select className
    ;
    io:println("classNames: ", classNames);

    // 2/3 helper function for building an array of students names of a class
    var findStudentNamesOf = function(string className) returns string[] {
        return 
            from Student student in students ?: []
            where student.className == className
            select string`${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
        ;
    };

    // 3/3 classes to list of student names
    map<string[]> classStudents = 
        map from string className in classNames
        select [className, findStudentNamesOf(className)]
    ;
    io:println("classStudents: ", classStudents);
}
```

Prints:

```
classNames: ["Biology","Economics","Physics"]
classStudents: {"Biology":["Curt Christison"],"Economics":["Garnett Attwood"],"Physics":["Lynton Dobson","Kerrie Adkins"]}
```

as expected.